# biblatex ieee style weird paranthesis after an update

Tags: biblatex, ieee-style

I want to get rid of the weird parenthesis around the number in the `\textcite` command. It did not used to be there. I think it all happened after an update. Also if you use hyerref the number and brackets are linked.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@Article{Yang09,
    author = "Hukun Yang and Hongyuan Jiang and Antonio Ramos and Pablo Garc{\'i}a-S{\'a}nchez",
    title = "AC electrokinetic pumping on symmetric electrode arrays",
    journal = "Microfluidics and Nano{\-}fluidics",
    publisher = "Springer Berlin / Heidelberg",
    issn = "1613-4982",
    keyword = "Physics and Astronomy",
    pages = "767--772",
    volume = "7",
    issue = "6",
    url = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10404-009-0434-5",
    year = "2009"
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
This is referred in \cite{Yang09} or \textcite{Yang09}.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Based on @Herbert answer, the problem is partially solved however the hyperref problem still exists. Can only the number be in color?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}%
    \ifbool{bbx:subentry}
      {\printfield{entrysetcount}}
      {}}}
\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\cbx@tempa
     \ifnameundef{labelname}
       {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
       {\printnames{labelname}}%
     \addspace\bibopenbracket}%
  \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{cite}%
  \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
  \gdef\cbx@tempa{\bibclosebracket\multicitedelim}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{ref.bib}
\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@Article{Yang09,
    author = "Hukun Yang and Hongyuan Jiang and Antonio Ramos and Pablo Garc{\'i}a-S{\'a}nchez",
    title = "AC electrokinetic pumping on symmetric electrode arrays",
    journal = "Microfluidics and Nano{\-}fluidics",
    publisher = "Springer Berlin / Heidelberg",
    issn = "1613-4982",
    keyword = "Physics and Astronomy",
    pages = "767--772",
    volume = "7",
    issue = "6",
    url = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10404-009-0434-5",
    year = "2009"
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
This is referred in \cite{Yang09} or \textcite{Yang09}.
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: I'll take (yet) another look at this. I'm beginning to suspect there may be a an issue in `biblatex` with the way `labelitem` is handled.

Comment: Problem hopefully located: will update CTAN soon.

Answer (score 6):

use

```
[...]
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}%
    \ifbool{bbx:subentry}
      {\printfield{entrysetcount}}
      {}}}
\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\cbx@tempa
     \ifnameundef{labelname}
       {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
       {\printnames{labelname}}%
     \addspace\bibopenbracket}%
  \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{cite}%
  \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
  \gdef\cbx@tempa{\bibclosebracket\multicitedelim}}
\makeatother
[...]
```

Comment: Probably what I'll do, but I'm concerned that the general business with `labelnumber` is much more complicated that it should be.

Comment: Thanks. Still there is an issue with label number and hyperref. Question is updated now.

Comment: @rowman: I cannot see it when I use `\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%`. I have current TeXLive 2012

Comment: Strange. I also have updated TeXLive 2012. I am using Ubuntu. Anyway, might be easier to wait for the update to CTAN. Thanks !